# How can you get numeric outputs from an alphanumeric(Pyautogui)

Tags: python

How can you get only numeric outputs from

`pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Capture.png')`

if `pyautogui` can't find the picture on the screen you will get an output of; None or if `pyautogui` finds the picture on the screen it will give an output such as; Box(left=1416, top=562, width=50, height=41)

is it possible to only take the numbers form the output?.

Comment: Do you want to get the number of left, top, width, height?

Comment: yes i want the left, top, width, height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [document](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) of `pyautogui`, You could use:

```
location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Capture.png')
if location != None:
    x, y, w, h = location
```

Or:

```
if location != None:
    x, y, w, h = location.left, location.top, location.width, location.height
```